# Clojure Macro using filter returns an object reference. Do not know how to interpret this reference

Tags: clojure, macros

I am defining this `macro`

```
seminar.core=> (defmacro select
          #_=>     [vara _ coll _ wherearg _ orderarg]
          #_=>        `(filter ~wherearg))
#'seminar.core/select
```

And then defining a table

```
(def persons '({:id 1 :name "olle"} {:id 2 :name "anna"} {:id 3 :name 

"isak"} {:id 4 :name "beatrice"}))
```

When I try to run my `macro`, so that I get the columns from the table where the id is greater than 2 (i.e `{:id 3 :name "isak"} {:id 4 :name "beatrice"}`)

```
    seminar.core=> (select [:id :name] from persons where [> :id 2] orderby :name)
```

I receive the following message and do not know quite how to interpret it

```
#object[clojure.core$filter$fn__4808 0x18e53c53 "clojure.core$filter$fn__4808@18e53c53"]
```

## Update

I added a second argument to filter

```
seminar.core=> (defmacro select
          #_=>     [vara _ coll _ wherearg _ orderarg]
          #_=>        `(filter ~wherearg ~coll))
```

and receive `IllegalArgumentException Key must be integer  clojure.lang.APersistentVector.invoke (APersistentVector.java:292)` as my return value now. I do not know how to interpret this error

Comment: What does `filter` return when you give it only one argument? http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/filter

Comment: @GregHendershott Of course sorry. I posted the edit with two arguments, but am still receiving an IllegalArgumentExcpetion error. I do not know how to interpret this.

Comment: I recommend two distinct steps. 1. Without a macro, write/debug/understand some code. 2. Only then, create a macro that writes step 1's code-that-works. (If I try to do it as one big step, I usually regret it. I say that as someone who's written quite a few macros in Clojure and Racket.)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `macroexpand-1` function to see the expanded form of macro it may give you a clue:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(select [:id :name] from persons where (> :id 2) orderby :name))
;;=> (clojure.core/filter [> :id 2] persons)
```

The form `[> :id 2]` isn't a valid function definition in Clojure. You have to pass proper function to `filter`, e.g. using anonymous function:

```
(select [:id :name] from persons where #(> (:id %) 2) orderby :name)
;;=> ({:id 3, :name "isak"} {:id 4, :name "beatrice"})
```